# Loading a file as a string content in a Spring service contained in a JAR built with Maven

Tags: spring, maven, file-io, singleton

I am using **Spring** with **Maven** and I would like to load a file contained in the maven folder `src/main/resources` inside a spring service annotated with `@Service` contained in a `JAR` file (used by another `WAR` file as a Maven dependency). This does not seem to work for many different reasons (read: for many different exceptions according to many different attempts).

- I know that Maven, when building, puts the stuff in `src/main/resources` at the root of the `JAR` file. I've opened the `JAR` file and I've verified that.
- I would prefer a `File` object (something I can use with utility libraries like Apache Commons IO), but also "something" else that's working is fine.
- I would prefere going for stuff within the Java class annotated with `@Service` (i.e. no application context XML file, with stuff inside that I recall within the service etc.)
- The file contains stuff that I eventually use as a `List<String>` where every item is a line in the original file. I need to keep this file as it is, I can not use a database or another solution different than a file.
- This is not a `.properties` file and is not intended to be.

The following are the not working attempts (throwing `NullPointerException`, `FileNotFoundException`, `IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical` and so on...).

**Among the attempts I have tried also adding/removing the prefix `src/main/resources`** while trying to figure out what was wrong, but then I figured out that Maven puts all the stuff at the root of the `JAR` file as stated before.

```
@Value("classpath:src/main/resources/myFile.txt")
private Resource myFileResource;

private File myFile = 
    new File(this.getClass().getResource("/myFile.txt").toURI());

private File myFile = 
    new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/myFile.txt").getFile();

private BufferedReader bufferedReaderMyFile = 
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myFile.txt")));
```

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: You say you have verified the content is in the JAR file in the root location? Then why are you using src/main/resources/myFile.txt? The root location in the JAR file would be "classpath:myFile.txt". Have you tried that?

Comment: And did you try `InputStream inStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("classpath:/myFile.txt");`, or same without `classpath:` ?

Comment: @RobBlake I've tried all the scenarios with/without prefix, I've edited the question highlighting in bold what I stated, I think the problem was related to the `/` just before the file name, see below in this comment. @Serge your suggestion worked only in the case without the `classpath:` prefix i.e. `/myFile.txt` thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` inside jar file is no longer a `File`, so treat it as `Resource` and read it via `Stream`

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myFile.txt");
```

assumming you have actually packed that `myFile.txt` inside jar file and it is available at the root of JAR file

Comment: This version worked for me as well: `MyCystomSpringService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile.txt")`

Comment: The difference between a resource and a file (with respect to absolute paths or relative paths to the classpath of, for example, a webapp) is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream